# Usage of postfix notation for quantifiers

Tags: notation, logic

All the logical notations I've seen, from the [Begriffschrift notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift) on, place quantifiers before the proposition containing the variables the quantifier binds. For example, in modern notation we have well-formed formulas like the following.

$$ \forall x \mathop. \exists y \mathop. P(f(x), y) $$

I think it took a while for the choice of $\forall$ and $\exists$ as universal and existential quantifiers to stabilize, but I'm curious about their order relative to the formula associated with the quantifier. I'm wondering if there's historical usage of postfix quantifiers (strawman syntax shown below).

$$ P(f(x), y) \;\; \exists[y] \; \forall[x] $$

Comment: [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) has been implemented in computers, but computer language has no quantifiers.

Comment: I've only relatively recently realized that standard English, even in a mathematically precise context, does allow quantification after the predicate. On one hand, this is standard English, and flows well, and is comprehensible ... but, on another hand, it does potentially allow confusions about order of quantifiers, uniformity, etc. No easy fix.

Comment: @paulgarrett ... I think you're right that ambiguity would exist if both orders were permitted. My question is meant to be about picking the quantified-quantifier order rather than potentially allowing both.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, ah, indeed. I do not know the history of these conventions...